# Wordpress Media Video to start at certain time and autoplay when focus

Tags: wordpress, video, media

In my homepage I have a video from the wordpress media, I wanted to know if there's a way to start the video at a given time, and autoplay it only when focusing.

Answer (score 0):

```
 setTimeout( function(){ 
    jQuery('.wp-video video').get(0).play(); 
  }  , 1000 );

jQuery(document).on('mouseover', '.wp-video', function(){ 
    jQuery(this).find('video').get(0).play() 
});

jQuery(document).on('mouseout', '.wp-video', function(){ 
  jQuery(this).find('video').get(0).pause() 
});
```

Comment: in a js file of your theme

Comment: I putted it inside Divi -> Integration inside the head tag and body tag and it didn't worked, I noticed non of the elements wich contain the video as a class(<video controls><source type="video/mp4" src="..."/></video)

Comment: This is js code, first It must be in footer to load after jquery and you should add it to js file, I don't know if you know how to make a child theme and add it there in a custom js file.